# Switch Users in unix automatically

Tags: shell, unix

This might be a newebie question. I would like to automatically switch between users. I know that we can use "expect" programming. Is there any alternative way ?

Comment: Care to expand a little more? As in which way you would like to switch between users; in the terminal, desktop sessions, remove desktops/servers?

Comment: @mhitza, i would like to switch users in console/terminal, using "su" or any other alternative way [ if possible ].

Comment: `su - foobar` to switch to user `foobar` (as you already know of based on your last comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using su has already been mentioned:

```
su - <username>
```

But more restricted access to other user accounts can be granted using sudo:

```
sudo -u <username> <command>
```

Sudo supports many options. See /etc/sudoers and man sudoers.

To always run an executable or a script as another user, without using any tools like su or sudo, or to build your own tool for your current purposes, use the setuid mode:

```
chown <username> <executable>
chmod u+s <executable>
./<executable>
```

For example:

```
$ id -un
atnnn
$ cp /usr/bin/id .
$ sudo chown nobody id       
$ sudo chmod u+s id
$ ./id -un
nobody
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want, and how you're accessing your machine.  It is easy enough to create windows (xterms or whatever) and arrange for different terminals to run as different users - at least after you've created them.  You can use 'su' or (better) 'sudo' to become another user.  (I'm assuming you're authorized to become that other user - it isn't the ID of a colleague, but of some test user that you need to experiment with.)

If you want to switch between terminal sessions as different users at a single window, then you have to work a bit harder.  There are programs to do that: it used to be `shl` (shell layers) and I think the modern equivalent is [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  I've not used GNU Screen (and I haven't used `shl` since about 1990); I work with different terminals connected as, or running as, the different users when I need to work as multiple users.